# How to use socket.io in iOS and in Android using phone gap and html5 for chat application

Tags: android, ios, iphone, html, cordova

We are using socket.io in web application. It is working fine. How to use socket.io in iOS and in Android for chat application.We are using phone gap for developing an application in both platforms.Can any one help me for this,Thanks in advance.